# Clear sessions and old cookies in ASP.Net Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a website with a lot of registered users and many of them have chosen the "remember me" option in login.

I used to use the default login behavior for asp.net core but I installed openiddict and added the following option to services.addIdentity:

```
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
    }
```

The full method in startup.cs now reads the following:

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieDomain = "mydomain.com";
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
```

The problem now that if a previously registered and logged-in user tried to open pages that require authentication he gets an error message. Unfortunately I'm unable to determine that error because appinsights and "development" mode doesn't work for me in Azure. if users go to login page without logging out they get a blank page after logging in.
The only way to solve it is to logout and login again.

Because I have a lot of users I'm trying to find a way to clear all sessions or previous cookies.
Any suggestions on this or comments about my code above is strongly appreciated.

Thank you

Update: I tried try catch and the error happened. Apparently there is no exception... This is very weird.

Update2: This is not account related. A friend of mine is facing the error and gave me his credentials. When I tried it works, perhaps it's a cookie problem?

Comment: What is the statuscode of the blank page?

Comment: Cant you just change the name of the application cookie and that should invalidate any previous cookies ...